# How to move an image to the mouse position in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting slowly back to javascript and I'm a bit lost on basics. 
I just want to move an image to follow the mouse position.
Here is a simple code I've been tweaking for some time without any success :

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="avatar" src="Klaim.png" style="position:absolute;" />
</body>

<script lang="javascript">

function updateAvatarPosition( e )
{
    var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
    avatar.x = e.x;
    avatar.y = e.y;

    // alert( "e( " + e.x + ", " + e.y + " )" );    
    // alert( "avatar( " + avatar.x + ", " + avatar.y + " )" );
}

document.onmousemove = updateAvatarPosition;


</script>

</html>
```

It looks a lot like some tutorials to do this very thing.
What I don't understand is that using the alerts (I don't know how to print in the browser's javascript console) I see that avatar.x and y are never changed. Is it related to the way I've declared the image?

Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would never try to do this sort of thing in native javascript: since I started using a javascript library, the language has changed for me from a horror to something I use readily. I use prototype/scriptaculous, but there are others. Jquery seems to be the most popular.

Comment: I agree and I'm planning to learn JQuerry, but first I had to do this one to show something at my dayjob. It's complete, not code that will change, and it's only for a demo, so it will be trashed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you don't want to set `x` and `y`, but rather `style.left` and `style.top`!

```
avatar.style.left = e.x;
avatar.style.top = e.y;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `x` and `y` property for avatar - you should use `'top'` and `'left'` instead. Also, move the `var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");` declaration outside of the function, as you only need to do this once.

Comment: +1 : now the avatar.top and left does get updated but it don't seems to be enough to make it move :/

Comment: Yeah - @Sascha's answer is correct, they are properties of the `style` property, not of the `avatar` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="avatar" src="Klaim.png" style="position:absolute;" />
</body>

<script lang="javascript">

function updateAvatarPosition( e )
{
    var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
    avatar.style.left = e.x + "px";
    avatar.style.top = e.y + "px";

    //alert( "e( " + e.x + ", " + e.y + " )" );    
    //alert( "avatar( " + avatar.x + ", " + avatar.y + " )" );
}

document.onmousemove = updateAvatarPosition;


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
avatar.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
avatar.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
```